# Regex for delimiters, except in numbers

Tags: c#, regex

Using C#'s Regex.Split, I have a regex that finds delimiters between words:

```
[\b\s\p{P}]+
```

On "**sample text. another:word**" it works, and produces: **sample** | **text** | **another** | **word**. Great!
On "**word 120,000 another word**" it produces: **word** | **120** | **000** | **another** | **word**. Not great!

How can I change the regex so that commas inside numbers will not be matched? i.e, so that **120,000** will not break?

Comment: Could you tag and mention the language?

Comment: Sorry - I'm using C#. see edited question.

Comment: By the way, `\b` inside a character class doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will find that doing this with `Regex.Split` is only going to get more complicated as additional requirements emerge. You might find it preferable to use `Regex.Match` instead to do the reverse (recognize "whole words" instead of logical "word boundaries").

Here's why:

```
((?<=\p{L})\p{P}(?=\p{L}))|(\p{Z}|(?<=[\p{Z}\p{P}])\p{P}|\p{P}(?=[\p{Z}\p{P}]))+
```

Not pretty, so let's explain it. First off, I have replaced `\s` with the `\p{Z}` class (visible/invisible whitespace) because why not. Second, this regex matches four different things:

### #1: `(?<=\p{L})\p{P}(?=\p{L})`

This matches a punctuation character that is sandwiched between letters. Needed to match the `:` in `another:word`. It's also the only subpattern on which the `+` quantifier does not apply (it would make no sense). Positive lookaround is used to assert the presence of the letters but avoid matching them.

### #2: `\p{Z}`

This matches a sequence of whitespace. All such sequences result in splits.

### #3: `(?<=[\p{Z}\p{P}])\p{P}`

This matches a punctuation character that is preceded by anything other than punctuation or whitespace, using positive lookbehind.

### #4: `\p{P}(?=[\p{Z}\p{P}])`

This is the converse of the above: it matches a punctuation character followed by anything other than punctuation or whitespace.

It follows that since the comma in `100,000` matches none of the above this regex will not split that token. But you can see where this is going: instead of specifying what symbols you *want* to keep together as one token, using `Regex.Split` you will have to specify... everything else.

Comment: Thanks - it works, and you are probably right about your belief...
But, isn't the reverse just as complicated? because the "if between numbers" logic is still there...

Comment: @seldary: Depends on your requirements. My intuition says it's better the other way, but YMMV.

Comment: @seldary: Works now, but let me tell you it's getting ugly. I couldn't have offered a better example of why *not* to do it this way.

Comment: Couldn't agree more - could you provide me with a more elegant approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(([\s\p{P}](?!\d))|((?<!\d)[\s\p{P}]))+
```

The first half

```
 ([\s\p{P}](?!\d))
```

matches any delimiters not followed by a number and the second - any delimiters, not following a number.